# ABCPDF Arabic Text Rendering Incorrectly

Tags: c#, abcpdf

When I am rendering Arabic text on a report, the text is not rendering correctly.  The text appears to be being rendered one individual letter at a time, rather than being joined up.

The text is being displayed right to left correctly (I've used the dir=rtl formatting on each element I'm adding), which is confusing me.

Any help anyone can give is appreciated.

I've added a screenshot of some text as an example.

[image: Arabic Text Issues]

Answer (score 0):

So I emailed abcpdf directly and they told me this:

ABCpdf 8 supports Arabic, but does not support contextual ligatures with the Doc.AddHtml approach - only with regular HTML/CSS (i.e. using Doc.AddImageUrl or Doc.AddImageHtml).

Support for contextual ligatures with Doc.AddHtml was added in ABCpdf 9.1 and is present in the current live release, ABCpdf 10.

Further clarification:

if I add an html file with the specific Arabic text onto my server, i should be able to access it and render the text in that file correctly?

That's correct. Please ensure you have the final ABCpdf 8 minor version (8123) from our Downloads page. And you may need to use the Gecko HTML engine - please see the HtmlOptions.Engine property.